# Using a function decorator for terminal spinning animation

Tags: python, animation, pip

My favorite package for terminal-based spinning waiting animation, [animation](https://web.archive.org/web/20161220184357/https://pypi.python.org/pypi/animation/0.0.1), has just been removed from `pip` today. I'm surprised, I didn't know they removed packages. It's still indexed by Google and I installed it on a VM just this morning and never had any issues with it. It's clearly gone from `pip` though and no longer indexed.

What distinguished it from the other packages I looked at was its ease of use, with a simple decorator on a function that was expected to take a long time:

```
@animation.simple_wait
def long_running_function():
    ...
```

I took a look at the other ones, but none of them are as convenient as `animation` as they don't use a simple decorator. [progress](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progress) you need to manually call `spinner.next()`, same with [pyspin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyspin/1.0.2). That's not always convenient.

Is there another package that offers a decorator for a spinning animation? or how could I make my own decorator by leveraging one of these other packages?

Comment: Have you asked the author why this has happened? Depending on the license the package was released under, you may be able to re-publish it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use packages from pip only. In fact, big projects are using a local copy of 3rd-party code. So they save themselves from issues like you have. Look at chromium [sources](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/). There you can find a folder called *third_party*, where all external code located. For instance: libxml.

So you can just grab *animation* from github and install it manually. Considering you are using virtualenv:

```
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
git clone https://github.com/bprinty/animation.git
cd animation
python setup.py install
```

Or you can  write your own decorator in the same way as they did. The [code](https://github.com/bprinty/animation/blob/master/animation/decorators.py) is pretty obvious.